# How do you bundle Meteor apps on another platform using 0.6.6?

Tags: meteor

I have a Meteor app, developed on a Mac, which I push to Github.  I then pull down changes from Github to my production server and, in the app directory on the production server, do:

```
sudo mrt bundle ../bundle.tgz
```

... which creates a bundle I can then unpack and run using:

```
cd ../
sudo tar -zxvf bundle.tgz
cd bundle
node main.js
```

After updating to 0.6.6.1, this stopped working.

Now, when trying to bundle the app on the production server, I get:

> Stand back while Meteorite does its thing
>
> Done installing smart packages
>
> Ok, everything's ready. Here comes Meteor!
>
> Errors prevented bundling:
>
> While building the application:
>
> server/node_modules/fibers/build.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
>
> server/node_modules/fibers/test.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

So I bundled the app on my Mac, used a FTP client to transfer the bundle.tgz file to the production server, unpacked the tarball, then did the necessary:

```
cd bundle/programs/server
sudo npm remove fibers
sudo npm install fibers
```

and started the node process and everything worked fine.

My question is, why can't I bundle the app on the production server anymore? Anyone else come across something like this?

Comment: What version of node are you running on your production box?

Comment: Using node v0.10.20 on both production and dev boxes.

Comment: I just did the same upgrade today on my ubuntu server and everything went fine on the first try. I wish I had an answer for you. I always do a clean build of node (blow away the binaries and module dirs), but I don't know if that would make a difference here or not.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that. Must be something specific to my setup. I'll keep trying things over the next few days and post back here if I come up with a solution.

Comment: @jackadams49 Have you found a solution? If so, please put it into an answer and accept it so we can keep the unanswered questions list clean.